# How to prevent Bootstrap classes from overlapping?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have just started learning Bootstrap and am trying to implement it in a web page. But I am having trouble in preventing the bootstrap class divs from overlapping each other. On full screen, the web page looks like:
[image]

On reducing the width of the window by some amount, it becomes:
[image]

And making window almost as small as mobile screen I get this:
[image]

My html code for this is:

```html
<body>

  <div id="point" class="row container-fluid">
    <div id="point_display" class="col-md-10">

    </div>
    <div id="point_info" class="row col-md-2">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h5>Current point position:</h5>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="checkbox" id="coordinate_transform" onclick="transformCoordinate(this.checked)"><span>Transform co-ordinate system</span></input>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h5>Transformation matrix:</h5>
        <div id="transformMatrix">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="control" class="row container-fluid">
    <div id="slider" class="col-md-2">
      <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" oninput="changePosition(this.value)" onchange="changePosition(this.value)" />
    </div>
    <!--div id="coordinate" -->
    <div class="col-md-3"><span>X: </span><input id="newX" type="number" step="0.0001" value=1 00></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><span>Y: </span><input id="newY" type="number" step="0.0001" value=1 00></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><span>Z: </span><input id="newZ" type="number" step="0.0001" value=- 300></div>
    <!--/div-->
    <div class="col-md-3"><button id="change_destination" onclick="setNewDestination()">Set New Destination</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button id="reset_camera" onclick="resetCamera()">Reset Camera</button></div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main_script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The black part of the page with axes and stuff is dynamically added to the div with id= `point_display` inside div `point` and the matrix is also dynamically added in the div with id = `transformMatrix"

Please help me figure out how to prevent the overlapping of the elements so that on reducing width, they just stack one below other.

Comment: Please also add the relevant css to your post

Comment: first of all, try not to mix tags for grid building. eg. don't do it like this: `<class="row container-fluid">` or `<div class="row col-md-2">`. Make it as a separate tags, eg. `...<div class="col-md-2"><div class="row">...`

Comment: @Cichy did that but the problem still persists